# iText: convert html and css to PDF in Java

Tags: java, html, css, pdf, itext

I'm trying to convert HTML to PDF. Firstly, I converted my HTML code to XHTML from the following link.
http://www.cruto.com/resources/code-generators/code-converters/html-to-xhtml.asp

Then, to test it, I created a HTML file with generated XHTML code and it displayed successfully on browser. After that, I tried to convert the HTML file to PDF with the following java code.

```
public static final String DEST = "C:/Users/Turgut/Desktop/test12.pdf";
public static final String[] HTML = { "C:/Users/Turgut/Desktop/New Text Document (5).html", "C:/Users/Turgut/Desktop/New Text Document (5).html" };

public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file = new File(DEST);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    new TestHtmlToPdf().createPdf(DEST);
}

public void createPdf(String file) {
    Document document = new Document();
    try {
        //String HTML = "C:/Users/Turgut/Desktop/test12.html";
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
        document.open();
        String css = readCSS();
        for (String htmlfile : HTML) {
            String html = Utilities.readFileToString(htmlfile);
            ElementList list = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(html, css);
            for (Element e : list) {
                document.add(e);
            }
            document.newPage();
        }
        document.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(DocumentException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String readCSS() throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    InputStream is = XMLWorkerHelper.class.getResourceAsStream("/default.css");
    while ((length = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        baos.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    return new String(baos.toByteArray());
}
```

I have a style tag in the head tag like below.

```
<style type="text/css">
                body {
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
                font-family: 'Tahoma', "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
                font-size: 11px;
                color: #666666;
                }
                h1, h2 {
                padding-bottom: 3px;
                padding-top: 3px;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
                color : #000000;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                }
                h5 {
                padding-bottom: 0px;
                padding-top: 0px;
                margin-top: 0px;
                margin-bottom: 0px;
                color : #000000;
                font-style: normal;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 1em;
                text-transform:none;
                }
                h5x {
                padding-bottom: 0px;
                padding-top: 0px;
                margin-top: 0px;
                margin-bottom: 0px;
                color : #000000;
                font-style: bold;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 1em;
                text-transform:none;
                }                   
                h6 {
                padding-bottom: 0px;
                padding-top: 0px;
                margin-top: 0px;
                margin-bottom: 0px;
                color : #666666;
                font-style: normal;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 1em;
                text-transform:none;
                }

                h1 {
                font-size: 1.4em;
                text-transform:none;
                }
                h2 {
                font-size: 1em;
                color: brown;
                }
                h3 {
                font-size: 1em;
                color: #333333;
                text-align: justify;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                }
                h4 {
                font-size: 1.4em;
                font-style: bold;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                color: #000000;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                }
                h4x {
                font-size: 1.4em;
                font-style: bold;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                color: #666666;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                }
                hr {
                height:2px;
                color: #000000;
                background-color: #000000;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
                }
                p, ul, ol {
                margin-top: 1.5em;
                }
                ul, ol {
                margin-left: 3em;
                }
                blockquote {
                margin-left: 3em;
                margin-right: 3em;
                font-style: italic;
                }
                a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #70A300;
                }
                h7 {
                font-size: 1.1em;
                font-style: bold;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                color: #000000;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                }
                a:hover {
                border: none;
                color: #70A300;
                }
                #customerPartyTable {
                border-width: 1px;
                border-spacing: 0px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: #FFFFFF; 
                border-collapse: collapse;
                background-color: #FFFFFF
                }
                #lineTable {
                border-width:2px;
                border-spacing:;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: #000000; 
                border-collapse: collapse;
                background-color:;
                }
                #lineTableTd {
                border-width: 1px; 
                padding: 1px;
                border-style:  none solid none none;
                border-color: black;
                background-color: white;
                }
                #lineTableTh {
                border-width: 1px; 
                padding: 1px;
                border-style:  none solid none none;
                background-color: white;
                }
                #lineTableTrx {
                border-width: 0px; 
                padding: 0px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: #000000;
                background-color: white;
                -moz-border-radius:;
                }
                #lineTableThx {
                border-width: 1px; 
                padding: 1px;
                border-style:  none solid solid none;
                background-color: white;
                }
                #lineTableTr {
                border-width: 0px; 
                padding: 0px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: #000000;
                background-color: white;
                -moz-border-radius:;
                }
                #lineTableBudgetTd {
                border-width: 0px;  
                border-spacing:0px;
                padding: 1px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: #000000; 
                background-color: white;
                -moz-border-radius:;
                }                    
                table {
                border-spacing:0px;
                }
                td {
                border-color:#000000; 
                }</style>
```

There is no problem to generate PDF file from the HTML file, but I can not read css block i guess. Because, PDF file and HTML file is not same. In the PDF file some text's colors are different from HTML file.

How can I generate a PDF file with css? Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: Have you got the solution ?  I am also stuck at this. My html page with inline css looking perfect on browser, but when pdf generated css seems to disturb and some component not appearing, please help

Answer (score -1):

```
    ByteArrayInputStream html = new ByteArrayInputStream(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(htmlSource)));
    ByteArrayInputStream css = new ByteArrayInputStream(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(cssSource)));
    html = getHtmlByteArrayStream(); //this is only for my picture not neccessary 
    // step 1
    Document document = new Document();
    // step 2
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(destPdf));
    writer.setInitialLeading(12);
    // step 3
    document.open();

    // step 4
    XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, html, css);

    // step 5
    document.close();
```

this is how i do.

Comment: @Tksknl Have you got the solution?